# Securely join a Linux EC2 instance to a Managed AD domain automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am trying to configure an AWS ParallelCluster cluster to securely and automatically join an AWS Managed AD domain.

I can join the instances to the domain easily by using a `post_install` script. The issue I have is that I cannot find a way to not expose the credentials of the account used to join the instances to the domain.

My current solution is store the password in Secrets Manager, and use an EC2 role that grants access to that password. However, this means that any user logged-in to these instances can query that password.

Is there a way to provide the credentials to the instance without relying on an EC2 role?

Comment: You could use a non-EC2 role, but you'd have to put the creds for that IAM user in the script.

Comment: Unfortunately, with ParallelCluster, the script must reside in a bucket that the instance has access to, so that also exposes the credentials.

Comment: I am having the same problem. Still looking for a solution. The best thing I can think of is saving credentials in some sort od keytab suvh that only root can read from.

Comment: I believe I ended up using a Lambda function to read the credentials off Secrets Manager, and run a command on the instance with Systems Manager RunCommand. A bit of a pain, as you need to make sure that all components have properly scoped permissions: the Lambda Function, the SSM document... There are probably better solutions.